# Conditional calculated form

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form which auto calculates the selections in real time.

In the script below, there is an example of two form selection fields, they both have their values for the calculation, however I am wondering if its possible to have the 2nd select form have a value that multiplies with the selection from the first one?

Meaning the first one "man" is $60 per manpower, Second one "Stairs" is $30 per stairs.

I would want it to be $30 per stairs per manpower. So if 2 Manpower is selected, the stairs would actually be $60 per stairs.

Any way to work around this?

The form:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <select id="man" input name="man" class="calculate">
       <option data-price="0" value="">0</option>
       <option data-price="60" value="Manpower x 1">1</option>
       <option data-price="120" value="Manpower x 2">2</option>
       <option data-price="170" value="Manpower x 3">3</option>
    </select>

    <select id="stairs" input name="stairs" class="calculate">
       <option data-price="0" value="">0</option>
       <option data-price="30" value="Stairs x 1">1</option>
       <option data-price="60" value="Stairs x 2">2</option>
       <option data-price="90" value="Stairs x 3">3</option>
    </select>

    <dl class="total">
    <dt>Total</dt>
    <dd>$<span id="item-price"></span> SGD</dd>
    </dl>
```

The javascript:

```
<script>
 var basePrice = <?php $name = $_POST["item_price"]; echo $name; ?>; 
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("select.calculate").on("change", calc);
 $("input[type=checkbox].calculate").on("click", calc);
 $("#item-price").html(basePrice);
 $("#item_price_val").val(basePrice);
});
function calc() {
newPrice = basePrice;
$("select.calculate option:selected,input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function() {
  newPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
});
newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(0);
$("#item-price").html(newPrice);
$("#item_price_val").val(newPrice);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to follow your current code example but I will do my best to help.

- One main thing is your [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function was setup wrong.
- Also I have made use of the [data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) function to store some state.

See example below:

```js
var basePrice = 10;// Using 10 here so that its runable code.

function setupStairs() {
  // Generates a multiple to multiply start pice in #stairs by
  var multiple = $("#man").val().substr(-1);
  if ($("#man").val().length == 0) { multiple = 0; }
  
  // Simple 1 liner to disabled stairs if no manpower
  $("#stairs").prop("disabled", multiple == 0);
  // This will clear the value of stairs so that it is reset when manpower is changed
  $("#stairs").val("");
  
  // Sets the value of data-price in #stairs based on data-starting-price
  // Uses the last char in the value attribute of #man
  $.each($("#stairs option"), function() {
    var newPrice =  multiple * $(this).data("starting-price");
    $(this).data("price", newPrice);
  });
  
  // Code for testing
  $("#tdManPower").text(multiple);
  $("#tdManCost").text($("#man option:selected").data("price"));
}

function calc() {
  var manPrice = $("#man option:selected").data("price");
  var stairPrice = $("#stairs option:selected").data("price");
  var newPrice = manPrice + stairPrice;
  
  var total = basePrice + newPrice;
  $("#item-price").text(total);
  $("#item_price_val").val(total);
  
  // Code for testing
  var multiple = $("#stairs").val().substr(-1);
  if ($("#stairs").val().length == 0) { multiple = 0; }
  
  $("#tdBasePrice").text(basePrice);
  $("#tdStairs").text(multiple);
  $("#tdStairsCost").text(stairPrice);
  $("#tdTotal").text(total);
}

// To load the values for calc
$(function () { setupStairs(); calc(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="man" name="man" class="calculate" onchange="setupStairs(); calc();">
   <option data-price="0" value="" selected>0</option>
   <option data-price="60" value="Manpower x 1">1</option>
   <option data-price="120" value="Manpower x 2">2</option>
   <option data-price="170" value="Manpower x 3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="stairs" input name="stairs" class="calculate" onchange="calc();" disabled>
   <option data-starting-price="0" data-price="0" value="">0</option>
   <option data-starting-price="30" data-price="30" value="Stairs x 1">1</option>
   <option data-starting-price="60" data-price="60" value="Stairs x 2">2</option>
   <option data-starting-price="90" data-price="90" value="Stairs x 3">3</option>
</select>

<dl class="total">
  <dt>Total</dt>
  <dd>$<span id="item-price"></span> SGD</dd>
  <input id="item_price_val" type="hidden" />
</dl>

<!-- Table for testing -->
<table style="float:right; position:relative; top:-80px; right:50px;">
  <tr><td>basePrice</td><td id="tdBasePrice"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>manPower</td><td id="tdManPower"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>manCost</td><td id="tdManCost"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>stairs</td><td id="tdStairs"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>stairsCost</td><td id="tdStairsCost"></td></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr><td>total</td><td id="tdTotal"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The works somewhat, but i need my function to have a starting value from a previous page, which my original code does. and each selection value has "Manpower x 1" instead of "1" so when I click submit, the chosen selections comes out in full name instead of just "1". My code also lets a the total value be in hidden field so it can be brought forward to next page upon submit.

Comment: Ok I will try and update to reflect this info what is your math formula for the result? manpower * stair price + manpower price?

Comment: Basically the form has a starting value, and you can choose manpower, stairs, and other items as well. Some selections is to be multiplied depending on how many manpower has been chosen, others are fixed prices. The form above only has 2 examples, man and stairs.

Comment: So the final value should either be the default starting price (if nothing is chosen) or manpower + stair price * manpower + other price * manpower + other selections fixed price = total.

Comment: @DilMarc I think this is closer to what you where looking for let me know :)

Comment: Doesnt work as well as it used to. The old function script was best, with the new script, other parts of this form is now not functioning. Might have to re-write the entire script to get it all to work again. Is there a way to maintain my initial function script but to add a few lines to take the multiplier? the old one worked well, just didnt multiply. i think the onchange calc in the form also added to other parts not working, the old did that from the script itself and not from the form.

Comment: @DilMarc I am not sure where I am missing what you want so I have added some testing output. Let me know if that helps you tell me whats wrong.

Comment: Great! It works. Btw is there any way I can block selecting stairs if manpower has not been chosen? So if its zero, the stairs is not able to be clicked, only if chosen, it will be unlocked.

Comment: @DilMarc I have added your `disabled` feature :) upvote answer too.

Comment: @floe thanks! i have upvoted but it doesnt appear cos not 15 rep yet. You have been a great help.